# CSS - wrong linear-gradient

Tags: html, css

Why is the background gradient wrong at the end of the page if I resize the window?

http://jsfiddle.net/hca6zz20/2/ - better example of the gradient from red to blue

http://jsfiddle.net/hca6zz20/

```
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background-image: linear-gradient(#363663, #1b1b32);
  margin: 0;
}
```

[image: Result]

Comment: As you can see, I have `margin: 0;` on the body.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change:

```
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
```

To:

```
html,
body {
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/hca6zz20/6/)

[**FULLSCREEN DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/hca6zz20/6/embedded/result/)

Comment: The gradient repeats right at the end of `body` now, which if I'm not mistaken is not what the asker is looking for.

Answer (score 2):

your white div overflows so you need to change body from 100% to auto.

```
html,
body {
   height: auto;
}
```

Comment: please change html and body from 100% to auto it works.